# Perl - hash->Yaml->hash reduces quotation marks in numbers:

Tags: perl, yaml

I'm trying to insert a hash to a YAML file and later return it to the original hash.
(I'm doing it because I'm using multiple threads and want to merge them all at the end).

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
use YAML::XS;
use YAML qw(Dump);

sub PrintHash2Yaml {
    my ( $hash2Yaml, $yamlfilename ) = @_;

    open( FH, ">$yamlfilename.yaml" ) or die "can't open $yamlfilename.yaml : $!\n";
    print FH Dump($hash2Yaml);
    close FH;
}

sub yaml2Hash {
    my ($yamlfilename) = @_;

    # step 1: open file
    open my $fh, '<', "$yamlfilename.yaml" or die "can't open config file: $yamlfilename $!";

    # step 2: slurp file contents
    my $yml = do { local $/; <$fh> };

    # step 3: convert YAML 'stream' to perl hash ref
    my $yaml2hash = Load($yml);

    my $hashDebug = Dumper($yaml2hash);
    open( FH2, ">$yamlfilename.hash2" ) or die "can't open $yamlfilename.hash2 : $!\n";
    print FH2 $hashDebug;
    close FH2;

    return $yaml2hash;
}


my $hash1 = { 'hello' => '234' };
PrintHash2Yaml($hash1, "ex1");
my $hash3 = yaml2Hash("ex1");

print Dumper($hash3);
```

The output is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'hello' => 234
        };
```

I would have expected the value to be **'**234**'** and not just 234.
Any ideas how could I return it to '234'?

Thanks :)

EDIT:
I was told there is no difference in perl between those options and that perl relates to everything the same. That's enough for me.

Comment: Why do you need it? In Perl, there's no difference between numbers and strings.

Comment: I have a code that doesn't work and I'm trying to understand why with threads it doesn't work, but without threads it works fine. I'm looking at differences and this is one difference I found.
There's another one (I'll post later).
But if you say there's no difference, that does the job for me.

Comment: Are you sure all the modules you use are threads safe?

Comment: Hi, could you please explain what do you mean?
This question isn't related to any threads.

Comment: You can try use `LoadFile` instead `Load` and just one YAML module. The `Dump`  function has diferent behavior with quotation for each of these modules. Have a look in `$YAML::XS::QuoteNumericStrings` and `QuoteNumericStrings`.

Comment: Hi, I tried looking at it, but it still didn't work.
Couldn't find the thing about modules in the CPAN. Thanks for trying anyway :)

Comment: @urie: You mentioned threads first. I just wanted to know why you need to differentiate between numbers and strings.

Comment: You're right. At the end, I didn't need.
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

YAML.pm and YAML::XS might not handle numbers and strings correctly. YAML.pm is old anyway and shouldn't be used anymore.

While it is true that strictly there is no 100% reliable way to differentiate between numbers and strings, the variables have certain internal flags, and as long as they don't change, you can use [YAML::PP](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::PP) which will handle the flags (in the same way as currently JSON::PP does) to differentiate between numbers and strings by making a good guess. Simply replace your usage of YAML and YAML::XS with YAML::PP:

```
use YAML::PP qw( Load Dump );
```

and the output will be

```
$VAR1 = {
          'hello' => '234'
        };
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm not on Perl so much like I used to, so I can't remember even what I was working on. Thanks for helping others, though :)